# Get the index of an array entry using presto

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I have a table in presto ***with a column of JSON data*** and the json having 2 array entries:

Array "key-array":

```
[AAA, BBB, CCC]
```

Array "value-array":

```
[123, 456, 789]
```

The table would be of this format:

```
json-column
     
{"key-array":"[\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\"]", "value-array":"[\"123\",\"456\",\"789\"]","str_1":"abc"}
```

I would like to perform the following operations using presto query:

1. Search for a string inside array/column **key-array** and if it exists get its **index**.
2. Once I have the **index**, query array/column **value-array** and fetch the entry corresponding to the index.

What would the presto query be to print data in the following format:

```
Key  Value
AAA  123
BBB  456
CCC  789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just process the json and flatten it with [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(json_column) AS (
    VALUES 
        ('{"key-array":["AAA","BBB","CCC"], "value-array":["123","456","789"]}')
) 

-- query
select key, value
from (
    select cast(json_parse(json_column) as map(varchar, array(varchar))) parsed
    from dataset
) jt,
unnest(parsed['key-array'], parsed['value-array']) as t(key, value)
```

Output:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 123 |
| BBB | 456 |
| CCC | 789 |

P.S. casting to map is used cause I was not able to figure out json path escaping for presto, otherwise cast to map and `parsed[...]` would be replaced with `json_extract` and cast to `array(varchar)`.

**UPD**

Missed that the array values in json are double encoded, so they actually are json strings, not json arrays, so you need to parse them again:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(json_column) AS (
    VALUES 
        ('{"key-array":"[\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\"]", "value-array":"[\"123\",\"456\",\"789\"]"}')
) 

-- query
select key, 
    value
from ( 
    select cast(json_parse(json_column) as map(varchar, json)) parsed 
    from dataset 
) jt, 
unnest(
        cast(json_parse(cast(parsed['key-array'] as varchar)) as array(varchar)), 
        cast(json_parse(cast(parsed['value-array'] as varchar)) as array(varchar))
    ) as t(key, value)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. Your solution most definitely works. But, I have a generic scenario. What if the json object is not just a json of type **(varchar, array(varchar)))**? What then? I have updated my new Json string above in the description. In this case I receive the following error: **Cannot cast to map(varchar, array(varchar))**

Comment: @mang4521 there is a limit to how dynamic json can be for you to be able to handle it. In the updated case cast to `map(varchar, json)`, end then extract needed arrays and cat them - `cast(parsed['key-array'] as array(varchar))`. Also you can always use `try` and `try_cast`

Comment: Hi, is this what your are referring to?    Query::           **select key, value
from (
    select cast(json_parse(json_column) as map(varchar, json)) parsed
    from dataset
) jt,
unnest(cast(parsed['key-array'] as array(varchar)), cast(parsed['value-array'] as array(varchar))) as t(key, value)**

Comment: @mang4521 yes, exactly.

Comment: I tried it, but I get the following exception:    **presto error: Cannot cast to array(varchar). Expected a json array, but got ["AAA","BBB","CCC"]
"[\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\"]"**

Comment: @mang4521 can you post full json returned by `select json_column`? Possibly additional handling is needed here. Possibly there is some extra processing needed here.

Comment: This is the JSON I ran the query with:  ***{"key-array":"[\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\"]", "value-array":"[\"123\",\"456\",\"789\"]","str_1":"abc"***

Comment: @mang4521 see the update.

Comment: Works. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: One last question: I have multiple such rows and in some rows, if the array is null, I get the following exception: ***presto error: Cannot cast to array(varchar). Expected a json array, but got null***. Any work around this?

Comment: @mang4521 it depends on desired handling. You can always use `coalesce` for example.

Comment: If you don't really mind, could you kindly provide an example with coalesce? Where in the query provided by you should I add this function? I can skip those cases where key-array and value-array are null if that is what you are asking.
I am unable to find a solution here.

Comment: @mang4521 can you please give the example of the failing data?

Comment: Hi, This would be a good example.
***{"key-array":"", "value-array":"","str_1":"abc"}***